# File appears in Mac Finder, but not in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, google-drive

I am able to see a file in Mac Finder, but in Mac Terminal the file does Not appear in the directory listing using the command ls -al. The "find" command also does not find the file.

The containing folder is a sub-folder of a Google Drive folder. The folder appears empty in Terminal, but according to Mac Finder, the folder contains one .jpg file which I downloaded. Why is the file hidden from view in Mac Terminal?

If I login to Google Drive, I can see the file.  I can also open the image in Finder. But using terminal, the file just isn't there.   What gives?